# Need to compile Java program with TWO packages and MANY classes from command line but can't get syntax right

Tags: java, netbeans, javac

I have only used Netbeans to compile to this point. Now I have a complex project and though I have gotten compilation with errors, I don't know how to include the `gbl` package (lack of which led to many errors). Here's what I tried, among quite a few others:

`C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\WordyHelperton>`{COMMAND PROMPT}

`javac  -classpath src\masterwords;src\gbl  src\masterwords\*.java`

and

`javac  -classpath src\masterwords;src\gbl  src\*\*.java`

and

`javac  -classpath src\masterwords;src\gbl  -sourcepath src\*\*.java`

Here's the Netbeans directory structure:

[image]

Here's path to project:

`C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\WordyHelperton`

It's only critical to include `gbl` and `masterwords` packages, but I need `masterwords.res\dictionary`, if possible. 
(Here's path to it:

`C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\WordyHelperton\src\masterwords\res`)

Can I get a command line from someone, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to your src folder, then you can do:

```
javac -classpath masterwords\*.java gbl\*.java
```

Since you kept adding "src" to your classpath declaration, javac was looking for classes in a package like this:

```
src.masterwords.SomeClass
```

Comment: You need to be in your src folder.

Comment: @Gergely--Did you see that I had posted an error? I tried to erase it after a minute or two when I discovered that I WAS NOT in my src folder. Your command DID WORK for me.